# How can I find out when I subscribed to a YouTube channel?

Tags: youtube

I am trying to find out when I subscribed to a certain YouTube channel. I don't think I did.

I have searched and cannot find any way. Is there any way to learn when or how long I have been subscribed to a YouTube channel?

Comment: There is no such feature yet. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/cG8NCy0MUGQ

Answer (score 15):

- **go to https://xxluke.de/subscription-history/**
- **enter URL of your channel**
- **hit CONTINUE button**

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It worked perfectly.

Comment: Just verifying this method works quite nicely. 

Comment: And the privacy policy is reassuring, too: "A feature of this website, the „YT Subscription History“ uses the „YouTube API Services“ offered by Google to determine and display to you the subscriptions of a submitted YouTube channel including the time when the subscription started. For this the submitted user name or channel id gets send to the servers of Google. Neither the sent nor the received data is stored on our servers."

Answer (score 4):

Kind of a long way to do it but it was the only way I can find. I wanted to find out when I subscribed to someone, so to it I went to my YouTube channel and the first thing you see when you get there is your activity on YouTube. I knew the person I was searching for I was subscribed to for about a year so what I had to do was keep scrolling down until I found when I originally subscribed. As far as I saw it won't be an exact date so in my case it said a year, it could be anywhere from a year up to a year and 11 months. You still get an estimate of when you subscribed. Sorry for the long and vague answer, but it was all I could think of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Just go their channel, hit the about tab, send them a message and it tells you it has been sent and when you subscribed.

Comment: This sounds like a good answer. Could you back it up with a screenshot?

Comment: No, your method only posts the comment and says your message has been sent but no date is shown. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question specifically, but it does help. Go to your channel on YouTube and scroll down until you see the section "Subscriptions." By clicking on the bold face text "Subscriptions" it will show you all of your subscriptions in vertical list with the channel you most recently subscribed to at the top, your second most recent sub below that,  etc. So at the end of that list will be the first channel you ever subscribed to. Unfortunately, none of those entries have a date on them :(
That's all I have, sorry if it wasn't helpful, but, I hope what I provided was of some use.

Comment: I think this is "chance". My subscription list is not ordered by date (defaults to A-Z), and neither does this appear to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way: You go to the page you have subscribed, click on "About" and it tells you when you subscribed.

Comment: The "Joined" date on the _About_ page appears to be when the channel was created, not when I subscribed. I just subscribed to a random channel and the date shown was some time in 2007.

Comment: For some reason Google's "intelligent" search summary presents this wrong answer to questions like this. I guess deleting this answer would be the only way to stop the "institutionalized" spread of misinformation now.

Answer (score -1):

Just go to your YouTube channel and scroll to to subscriptions they should be in order by date.

Comment: The subscriptions list (ie. "Manage Subscriptions") can be sorted alphabetically (default), "Most relevant" and "New activity". Sorting by date of when they were subscribed does not seem to be possible.